# Check if method exists

Tags: android, reflection, methods

I want to check if the method `Camera.Parameters.getHorizontalViewAngle()` exists on the device (it's only available from API 8 and my min SDK API is 7). I tried to use "reflection", as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html), but it catches an error saying the number of arguments is wrong:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
```

Anybody could help?

```
Camera camera;
camera = Camera.open();
Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
Method m = Camera.Parameters.class.getMethod("getHorizontalViewAngle", new Class[] {} );
float hVA = 0;
try {
    m.invoke(params, hVA);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m.invoke(params, hVA);`

should be

`m.invoke(params, null);`

`Camera.Parameters.getHorizontalViewAngle()` doesn't take any arguments and the above line has the argument hVA. If you're looking for the return variable do `hVA = m.invoke(params, null);`

Comment: Can you give us the stack trace of the error? Also, where you have new Class[]{}, just put null as it treats that as an empty array.

Comment: You have the wrong number of arguments. Camera.Parameters.getHorizontalViewAngle() takes no arguments. I'm gonna edit my answer as it's easier

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I recommend conditional class loading, where you isolate the new-API code in a class that you only touch on a compatible device. I only use reflection for really lightweight stuff (e.g., finding the right `CONTENT_URI` value to use for `Contacts` or `ContactsContract`).

For example, [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Camera/Picture) uses two implementations of an abstract class to handle finding a Camera object -- on a Gingerbread device, it tries to use a front-facing camera.

Or, [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Menus/ActionBarBC) shows using the action bar on Honeycomb, including putting a custom View in it, while still maintaining backwards compatibility to older versions of Android.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a hack, but why can't you put the first call to the method in a try/catch of it's own, and nest the rest of your try/catch code in there.  If the outer catch executes, the method doesn't exist.

Comment: Because it won't compile since I'm compiling for API 7 and the method exists only from API 8.

Comment: #define #ifdef where you set the def once in main to the target version and then anywhere in the code you need it you use #ifdef ?

Comment: @jul: You can set your project to use the highest supported SDK version and then change the manifest 'uses-sdk' section as follows: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="<min_ver>" android:targetSdkVersion="<max_ver>" />. Substitute the appropriate numbers for <min_ver> and <max_ver>.